# Relacionar campo com tabela mysql

Tags: mysql, relacionamento, chave-estrangeira

Preciso fazer um CRUD de teste para uma empresa. Nesse teste, tive que criar os campos Nome, Email, Telefone e Endereço, e deveria ser possível inserir mais de um endereço por nome nesse CRUD. Acho que não da pra simplesmente criar outro campo para inserir outro endereço. Acho que o objetivo do teste é que eu crie relacionamento de tabelas, mas não faço ideia de como começar. Estou fazendo o CRUD com PHP e já tenho tudo pronto, adicionar, editar e excluir. Já está tudo funcionando. Só falta agora essa opção pra poder colocar mais de um endereço por nome. Vou colocar o código da classe e do BD. Se precisarem de mais algum é só avisar. Agradeço de antemão pela ajuda.

*SQL:*

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Nov 16, 2019 at 11:19 PM
-- Server version: 5.7.24
-- PHP Version: 7.3.7

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `crudoo`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `contatos`
--

CREATE TABLE `contatos` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `telefone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `contatos`
--

INSERT INTO `contatos` (`id`, `nome`, `email`, `telefone`, `endereco`) VALUES
(2, 'test2e', 'teste2@teste.com', '316497', 'rua a'),
(4, 'wanderson', 'sonwander@yahoo.com.br', '985930559', 'rua brasil'),
(6, 'andrezinho', 'andre@site.com', '2222222222', 'rua j');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `contatos`
--
ALTER TABLE `contatos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `contatos`
--
ALTER TABLE `contatos`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

*PHP:*

```
<?php
class Contato {

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=crudoo;host=localhost", "root", "root");
    }

    public function adicionar($email, $nome, $telefone, $endereco) {
        if($this->existeEmail($email) == false) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO contatos (nome, email, telefone, endereco) VALUES (:nome, :email, :telefone, :endereco)";
            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
            $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
            $sql->bindValue(':telefone', $telefone);
            $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
            $sql->execute();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getInfo($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contatos WHERE id = :id";
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sql->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $sql->execute();

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            return $sql->fetch();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    public function getAll() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contatos";
        $sql = $this->pdo->query($sql);

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            return $sql->fetchAll();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    public function editar($nome, $email, $telefone, $endereco, $id) {
        if($this->existeEmail($email) == false){
            $sql = "UPDATE contatos SET nome = :nome, email = :email, telefone = :telefone, endereco = :endereco WHERE id = :id";
            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
            $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
            $sql->bindValue(':telefone', $telefone);
            $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
            $sql->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $sql->execute();

            return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
    }

    public function excluir($id) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM contatos WHERE id = :id";
            $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(':id', $id);
            $sql->execute();
        }

    private function existeEmail($email) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contatos WHERE email = :email";
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $sql->execute();

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brother, sua pergunta está meio vaga. Está faltando mostrar o que você já tem pronto. Você citou nada sobre o seu código, linguagem, etc ... Edite a pergunta e mostre o que você já possui pronto.

Comment: Veja na documentação: [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) e particularmente: [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Endereço deveria ser outra tabela já que ele é um campo composto(rua, logadouro, numero, complemento), normalizar tabelas do banco pode fazer um diferença gigantesca, principalmente em sistemas que vão crescer muito

Comment: Como faço essa ligação entre tabelas? Quais serão os campos da tabela endereço e como ligar na outra? Vou ter que modificar o codigo PHP também, certo?